# ¿Cómo inserto datos de un párrafo a un input?

Tags: javascript, html, input

quisiera saber si se puede para que un texto que esta en un `<p></p>` me lo muestre en el Value de un input, aquí les dejo una imagen y mi código para que entiendan mejor.

[image]

```
<div class="mt-2">
    <div data-simple-toolbar="true" class="editor">
         <p>Content of the editor.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

aquí tengo una plantilla que descargue del internet pero en vez de ser un **textarea** es con un párrafo, yo escribo pero el texto me lo pone en un 



 y eso no me sirve por que para poder enviar la información por un formulario tiene que ser un input o un textarea no?, entonces quisiera que lo que escribo en el párrafo me lo muestre en un input oculto para así poder enviarlo por un formulario.

```
<input type="hidden" name="descripcion" id="descripcion" value="">
```

**No se si me lograron entender lo que quise decir**, espero su ayuda, gracias.

Comment: Hola, amigo te recomiendo que pases por aquí: [tour] y que te leas estos artículos: [help/dont-ask], [help/on-topic], [help/behavior] y que arregles tu pregunta mirando este articulo: [mcve] tambien puedes pedir ayuda en: [chat]

Comment: y que has intentado???

Answer (score 0):

En realidad no es muy complejo, tendrás que obtener el texto del div donde esta el párrafo, para esto tendrás que asignarle un ID, obtener ese valor en una variable y pasarle al input.

```js
function obtener_text() {
            // Obtenemos el texto
            let text_content = document.getElementById( 'content' ).textContent;
            // Lo asignamos al Boton
            document.getElementById( 'content_input' ).value = text_content;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Obtener Texto - JS</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="content" id="content"><p>Texto de prueba</p></div>
    <input type="text" name="content_input" id="content_input">
    <button onclick="obtener_text()">Asignar Texto</button>

</body>
</html>
```